# Windows 7 support for Intel PRO/Wireless 2200BG Network Connection

Tags: windows-7, drivers, wireless-networking

Is there compatible drivers for Intel PRO/Wireless 2200BG Network Connection adapter? Intel site says its discontinued : http://www.intel.com/support/wireless/wlan/sb/CS-030472.htm

Comment: Is it actually not working or do you want some functionality beyond the default Windows drivers?

Comment: its not working

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a laptop with this chipset built in with Windows 7.  The [Vista Drivers from Intel](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=15798&ProdId=1637&lang=eng) work just fine.  I picked the .zip file distribution, but either should work.  Note that the 2200BG only has 32-bit drivers, despite the presence of a 64-bit folder.  As far as I know there's no 64-bit drivers for this chipset.

Comment: I want the 32 bit drivers only.

Answer (score 0):

Not officially, but apparently there's a hack for making the XP drivers work. Have a look at [this](http://www.indiegameguy.com/blogs/zman/archive/2009/05/12/intel-pro-wireless-2200bg-drivers-for-windows-7.aspx) and [this](http://box.sonolento.com/?p=63).

Comment: Note that both the cited articles were created before Windows 7 RTMed.